# Server with web application for media

Tags: open-source, web-apps, server

I would like to create a server, on which I, and some other guests, can browse/download/upload/move/search/display pictures or videos (for the most cases).

That I don't want is to create a FTP server which isn't user friendly for newbies.

So I'm searching for a server packaged with a web application or a web application to add on a server.

Or any others (free) suggestions.

Comment: Something like owncloud? It like Dropbox that you can host yourself

Answer (score 0):

This is a "other suggestion", because it is not self hosted.

If you are looking for a file sharing tool, which is especially optimized for videos, I can recommend ARRI Webgate. I use it for video reviews, watermarking, metadata and direct links for users without an account.

My customers have high expectations of data protection laws. That's why it was important to me that the data was stored in Europe.

https://arriwebgate.com

Comment: Thanks, the web-app hosted on their servers look like something I'm looking for. Unfortunately it's not a free solution. I'm already paying for a dedicated server (and use it with other virtual servers). I prefer continue to use it rather than paid (again) for another solution.

Answer (score 0):

[MediaGoblin](https://mediagoblin.org/) seems to fit your description:

- Free Software - Affero GPL 3, part of the GNU project
- web interface for storing and sharing media files